# How to unlock linux user after too many failed login attempts

Tags: linux, user-accounts

After trying to login with the wrong password, my account is locked. When logging in on a TTY console I get the following message

```
mylaptop login: myUsername
The account is locked due to 3 failed logins.
(10 minutes left to unlock)
Password:
```

I am on Manjaro linux. I still have root access to this device.

How do unlock my user *without waiting 10 minutes*?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**If you still have access to the system by another account**
root or some other account with root-like (`sudo`?) privileges

1. You can view the failed logins with [`faillock`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/faillock)

   ```
   # faillock --user myUsername
   myUsername:
   When            Type     Source     Valid
   Timestamp 1     TTY      /dev/tty1  V
   Timestamp 2     TTY      /dev/tty1  V
   Timestamp 3     TTY      /dev/tty1  V
   ```

2. Reset them with the `--reset`-flag

   ```
   # faillock --user myUsername --reset
   # faillock --user myUsername
   myUsername:
   When            Type     Source     Valid
   ```

---

**If you've found another way to access the file system**
through a rescue disk or someone else's computer

1. Navigate to `/var/run/faillock` (*), this folder should contain a file with the locked username

   ```
   # ls /var/run/faillock
   myUsername
   ```
2. Remove the file with the username to unlock

   ```
   # rm /var/run/faillock/myUsername
   ```

*) This is called 'tally directory' and its location depends on your system's configuration, which is likely to be found at `/etc/security/faillock.conf`

Comment: This is a really good answer and should be accepted.

Comment: Strangely enough, removing the entry for my username under the /run/faillock directory does not unlock the account. The --reset command works though.

Comment: I've just tried and deleting the `/run/faillock/myUsername`-file still works on my machine. Apparently there are some configurations (some form of disk caching would be my first guess) that affect this behavior. Good to keep in mind.

Comment: instead of deleting manually let faillock handle it. Use command 

`faillock --reset --user <user> --dir <tally dir path>`

Comment: @VijaySB that is the preferred way and that is why it is part 1 of this answer

Answer (score 13):

#### **"sudo" and "faillock" - How to handle "The account is locked due to X failed logins."**

If you still have access with root-like privileges, you can view the failed logins...

```
faillock --user [USERNAME]
```

... and/or reset attempts status...

```
faillock --user [USERNAME] --reset
```

---

**PLUS:**

You can change the possible attempts number before a lock by uncommenting and changing the parameter...

```
# deny = 3
```

... in the file...

```
vi /etc/security/faillock.conf
```

Normally *faillock* automatically unlocks the account after 10 minutes (600 seconds), but you can change that too...

```
# unlock_time = 600
```

[Ref(s).: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-remove-or-increase-password-attempts/47986/2?u=eduardolucioac ]

Answer (score 0):

By default tally log is present in `/var/run/faillock`. If it is configured in `/etc/security/faillock.conf` to write in different path, then use below command.

`faillock --reset --user <user> --dir <tally dir path>`